# Unity3d Creating a text on mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

[image]

In 9 line FIXME_VAR_TYPE text ="PUT TEXT HERE";
shows error which is in below image , Can anybody solve this issue?

[image]

This is the error .

I am trying to change it String and var but also give error.

Comment: `Can anybody solve this issue?` .. you can by doing what it says and fix the type ^^ That should probably be a `string` for the first two and either `var` or `float` for the others  ...? Is that a homework assignment? -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) You should probably go through some basic c# beginner tutorials before jumping into Unity ...

Comment: Did you maybe try to convert js code to c#? In that case, the question on this forum might help you understand, what you did wrong https://forum.unity.com/threads/convet-fixme_var_type-to-c.145568/

Comment: Also. I dont recommend converting code like that, its like translating your essay from english to german with google translate. It does not work, the grammar is going to be all wrong and look like gibberish. Learn C# instead.

Answer (score 0):

This FIXME_VAR_TYPE does not exist currently.

> The type or namespace name 'FIXME_VAR_TYPE'

as the error says...
So here's how you can fix it:

On **lines 9 and 10** you seem to be trying to use the fields as **strings**.
This is how it should look like

```
string text = "PUT TEXT HERE" : line 9
private string currentToolTipText = "" : line 10
```

**On lines 36 and 37** you're using [Event.current.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-mousePosition.html) that is a [Vector2](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) that has two **float** components (X and Y).
This is how it should look like:

```
float x = Event.current.mousePosition.x : line 36
float y = Event.current.mousePosition.y : line 37
```